# Ask mysql database design

Tags: mysql, database

i'm new in mysql.. i want to ask about database design, i'll attach my design(sorry i've prevented to post images).. So i'll type the database. Can u please tell me which one better, and the reason.. Or there are better design for this kind database.??

First design:

```
tbl_member:
- id
- name

tbl_member_parent:
- id
- id_member
- parents_name

tbl_member_sibling:
- id
- id_member
- sibling_name
```

---

Or second design:

```
tbl_member:
- id
- name

tbl_relation_type:
- id
- relation:"parent","sibling" 

tbl_member_relation:
- id
- id_member
- id_relation_type
- name_value
```

---

maybe next, i will add (10-20) row in relation_type (like friends, neighbours).

In my opinion i should use the second, but i'm not pretty sure.. lol

Sorry if my english bad..

Thx alot..

---

@inhan
ic2.. yeah, i also think like that..
here is my mini database design..

Original:

> sex table
>   -  id INT auto_increment PK
>   -  sex varchar : "male","female"
>
> status table:
>   -  id INT auto_increment PK
>   -  status varchar :"active","notActive","problem"
>
> privilege table:
>   -  id INT auto increment PK
>   -  privilege varchar:"manager","moderator","member"
>
> country table:
>   -  id INT auto_increment PK
>   -  country varchar
>
> city table:
>   -  id INT auto_increment PK
>   -  city varchar
>   -  id_country INT, FK(to country table.id)
>
> job table:
>    -  id INT auto_increment PK
>    -  job varchar
>
> member table:
>    -  id INT auto_increment PK
>    -  member_name varchar
>    -  birthdate date
>    -  id_sex INT, FK (to sex table.id)
>    -  id_status INT,FK (to status table.id)
>    -  id_privilige INT, FK (to privilege table.id)
>    -  address varchar
>    -  id_city INT, FK (to city table.id)

since, people can have more than one nickname, siblings, freinds, job, nationality, etc

> memberJob table:
>    -  id INT auto_increment PK
>    -  id_member INT, FK (to member table.id)
>    -  id_job INT, FK (to job table.id)
>
> memberNationality table:
>    -  id INT auto_increment PK
>    -  id_member INT, FK (to member table.id)
>    -  id_country INT, FK (to country table.id)
>
> and then make memberNickname table; memberSiblings table; memberFriends table, etc

i want to change the table design for memberJob; memberNationality;memberSiblings; memberFriends

---

i think to make like this:

> relation table
>    - id INT auto_increment PK
>    - relation type varchar : "siblings", "freinds", "job", "nationality",
>
> memberDetail
>    - id INT auto_increment PK
>    -  id_member INT, FK (to member table.id)
>    -  id_relation INT, FK (to relation table.id) 
>    -  id_value INT, FK (if id_relation: sibling and friends then id_value FK to member table.id ; if id_relation:job then id_value FK to job table.id; if id_relation:nationality then id_value FK to country table.id)
>
> memberNickname
>    - id INT PK auto_increment
>    -  id_member INT FK (to member table.id)
>    -  nickname varchar

Is there anything wrong with that??

Answer (score 0):

A single table `members` with the following columns would be just fine.

- `id` INT auto_increment PK
- `name`
- `parent_id` INT default NULL, FK (to `id`)

So when you query all you need to do is use the same table to join. Those with no `parent_id` will be upmost level members whereas others will be children. To find siblings all you need to do is find children pointing to the same parent.

**[EDIT 1]**

If you want to have alternative kinds of relationships then you can create 2 other tables and ignore the `parent_id` column in the above table.

`relationshipTypes` table

- `id` INT auto_increment PK
- `rel_name`

and `relationships` table:

- `id` INT PK
- `user_id` INT, FK (to `members.id`)
- `rel_type_id` INT, FK (to `relationshipTypes.id`)

So you can select the user from `members`, then find all matching records in `relationships`, join that with `relationshipTypes` so you have all the information.

**[Comments for OP]**

Following remarks are my personal ideas.

1. Your `sex`, `status`, `privilege` tables are unnecessary since each member can have only 1 sex (gender), 1 status and 1 privilege, all of which can be enumarated (`ENUM`, speaking technically) in the `member` table.
2. Also, I would just forget about multiple nationalities and make the user pick 1 nationality. So this data too can be moved to the `member` table.
3. I would again keep the `city` data in the `member` table (as VARCHAR) while keeping a FK for the `country` to `country` table. Chances for this information can be enormous so it doesn't look feasable. For your system if you want to focus on a specific country (the target market) then you can have an enumated column with the city  list of that country, plus an "other" option and create an additional column for that "other" city, which can be of datatype `VARCHAR`.
4. Handling jobs is up to you. I don't know what you want your visual form to look like.

Comment: hey, thats great.. the reason why i choose to make "second design" is to reducing the amount of table.. because i've already make database design and it contain 70 tables.. and i think it is too much, because in some table only contain 2-6 row (to become foreign key to another table).. Is quantity of table affect the performance?? or the performance depend on the quantity of row??

Comment: @derpelp It depends on many things so a definite answer can not be given. But the structure above is all that there is - only 3 tables for all the users, nothing more. Otherwise creating so many tables that could actually be stored together in a single or a few tables does not sound a good database design to me.

Comment: hey inhan.. can u review my database once more.. i'll add the database design in question..
Thx you..